# When trying to open localhost it goes to error page. (xampp)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, localhost

I try to open localhost, but when I do in the control panel of xampp the service shutdowns and prints error:

> 11:18:37  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 11:18:37  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing
>   dependencies,
>
> 11:18:37  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by
>   another method.
>
> 11:18:37  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>
> 11:18:37  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 11:18:37  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 11:18:37  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums

Then I try to start it again and it says that it is working, however when I refresh the error page on localhost, SQL stops working again. I have changed the port on skype to a different than 80, if that is of any help.

Comment: Nope, it again shutdowns and stops localhost.

Comment: Sometimes I can reach the visual page of localhost, but everything, which should work in it, doesn't. Can't go to tables, databases, etc. And when I can see localhost, MySQL shutdowns from xampp and prints the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to do it.

1) Exit your `Skype` if you are using it.

2) Verify the Port number that the skype is using.If it is same as with `Mysql` port change the Mysql port number from its config file.

To change it follow the steps:

```
1. Stop the xampp server, if it is already running.
2. Go to folder "C:\xampp\apache\conf". (By default apache is installed in C folder)
3. Open the file httpd.conf.
4. Search the string "Listen" in the file.
5. Replace port number 80 to any other unused port number.
6. Search for "ServerName" in the file.
7. Replace port number 80 to any other unused port number in the ServerName.
8. Save the httpd.conf.
9. Start the xampp server.
```

Comment: I reach the localhost page, with a lot of patience, but MySQL again stops working.